# SSH config to access remote docker daemon API through <remote_ip>:<port> instead of localhost:<port>

Tags: docker, ssh, ssh-tunnel

For remote dev, I have set up docker daemon on a remote node (which requires SSH-only access and has ip  ) to listen for API requests through tcp port 2376 on that node, following instructions here: 
https://success.docker.com/article/how-do-i-enable-the-remote-api-for-dockerd

I can do `LocalForward 2376 localhost:2376` in my SSH config and it works, but then I have to query like this: `curl -X GET http://localhost:2376/images/json`

But, I want to query that API from my local laptop like this:
`curl -X GET http://<RemoteIP>:2376/images/json`

Would RemoteForward fix this? 
If so, what do I have to do to get RemoteForward to work?

A simple `RemoteForward 2376 localhost:2376` in my ssh config fails to forward: If docker.d is already running, it fails to forward during ssh connecting. If daemon is not running, then ssh tunnel works but the daemon service fails to start (with an uninformative error)

Comment: Why don't you just set up [Docker machine](https://docs.docker.com/machine/) to manage a remote instance? The only way to access `http://<RemoteIP/...` like that and have it work is if you have `curl` use an HTTP proxy.

Comment: If you actually ran the command on that Docker page, anyone on the network should be able to run `DOCKER_HOST=http://remote_ip:2376 docker run -v/:/host busybox cat /host/etc/shadow` among other things.  That setup makes unrestricted root-level access available to _anyone_ with no authentication or logging.

Comment: @tadman Thanks, I will look into Docker Machines to see if I can create remote docker hosts on already running EC2.

Comment: @DavidMaze How would it pass that command through to remote_ip:2376 without a SSH? Perhaps the ssh-only access was not clear from my question - made that explicit now.

Comment: `-H tcp://0.0.0.0:2376` makes the Docker socket access totally public (and is in many ways the equivalent of just disabling your root password).  The way your system is configured now _anyone_ who can reach it has root, without ssh or any sort of controls or logging.  Because of the security concerns, I'd really strongly suggest not trying to use the Docker API over the network at all.